# Overcome MAX_PATH filename length

Tags: c++, windows, fopen, file-attributes, long-filenames

I have read a lot of documentation on this subject, but I can't seem to figure it out.

The cause is that I have to process file paths which may be longer than the `MAX_PATH` parameter, causing a lot of issues

I have already replaced all my `ANSI`-functions like `GetFileAttributesA` with the `UNICODE` equivalent (`GetFileAttributesW`) in order to support the extended file path length with the prefix: `\\?\`.

However, I also need to check whether the file path for instance is a symbolic link and I need to know the filesize, last modified date, etc.

In order to do so, I use the `stat` function, as shown below:

```
if (fstat(LongFilePath, &file_info) == 0) //THIS FAILS WITH THE ENAMETOOLONG FOR LONG FILEPATHS
```

So, here again, the problem is in the `ENAMETOOLONG` error, due to a too long filename (exceeding `MAX_PATH`).

So, I found out I could use `fstat` to access the file by its descriptor. However, to obtain the descriptor, I need to use `fopen`, which also has the `ENAMETOOLONG` limitation.

So, my question is. How can I get the file information I need (symlink, filesize, last modified, .... as the `stat` function offers) for file paths exceeding `MAX_PATH`

Comment: You can use "GetFileInformationByHandle" win32 API, and if your application is running above Vista then "GetFileInformationByHandleEx" will be good.

Comment: @SOU, thanks this seems to work well! However, the date times seem strange to me. Some are in the range 30745230 (`ftLastAccessTime.dwHighDateTime`) and 2909209453 (`ftLastAccessTime.dwLowDateTime`). Both are wrong obviously, but why? The filesize for instance is correct

Comment: `_wstat` should work with a "\\?\" path, unless it's an old version of the C runtime library. Even with an old CRT, you should be able to use `_wopen` (not `fopen`) to get an fd and then `fstat`. However, the Windows CRT can't tell us whether a file is a symlink. For that you need `CreateFileW` with `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` and then `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` : `FileAttributeTagInfo`. The reparse tag will be `IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK`.

Comment: Thanks, I got the `GetFileInformationByHandle` working. However, I can't succeed in converting the `FILETIME` to a unix timestamp in UTC... Any advice?

Comment: @ThomasvanHesteren, we can use ``FileTimeToSystemTime`` to get the correct time using ``FILETIME``